# Swift Encode Lat&Lon to Polyline

Tags: swift, google-maps, latitude-longitude, polyline

I have a list of lat&lon, want to show it on map as a path. I could show polyline on the map by using GMSPath(fromEncodePath: polyline).

How could I convert lat&lon list as a polyline or display it on the map?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a path from coordinates like this

```
let path = GMSMutablePath()
path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(29.520,30.856))
path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.17,40.1235))
let pLine = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
```